# When is Applet.stop() called?

Tags: java, eclipse, swing, applet, japplet

I experiment with my applet using Eclipse and its Applet Viewer. The Applet Viewer appears on the top of Eclipse and during Applet execution I click on Eclipse icon to maximize it from task bar. Then Applet Viewer loses the focus and `Applet.stop()` gets called.

When I minimize Eclipse, Applet Viewer goes to front again, gains focus and `Applet.start()` gets called. This ends up in a complete mess.

**Is it normal behavior for a browser to call `Applet.stop` once user changes to another Tab or minimizes the browser Can I disable that, I want `stop` never been called.**

Maybe I am missing something in threads.

My code is something like this:

```
public class AppletApp extends JApplet {

    public void init() {
        super.init();
        System.out.println("AppletApp.init()");
    }

    public void start() {
        System.out.println("AppletApp.start()");

        try {
            SwingUtilities.invokeAndWait(new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    getContentPane().add(new JLabel("Test Label"));
                }
            });
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
        } catch (InvocationTargetException e) {}

        Runnable runnable = new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                //For DJ Browser Component
                NativeSwing.initialize();
                NativeInterface.open();

                //connect to server and start message exchange
                Client.init(userInterface);
                userInterface.authenticate();

                NativeInterface.runEventPump();
            }
        };
        Thread t = new Thread(runnable);
        t.start();
    }

    public void stop() {
        System.out.println("AppletApp.stop()");
    }

    public void destroy() {
        System.out.println("AppletApp.destroy()");
    }
}
```

Comment: stop is used when the browser considers that the applt should stop consuming resources (like CPU cycles for animation), this is not a decision you can make.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Is it normal behavior for a browser to call Applet.stop once user
>   changes to another Tab or minimizes the browser?

Yes it is normal. From the javadoc:

> Called by the browser or applet viewer to inform this applet that it
>   should stop its execution. It is called when the Web page that
>   contains this applet has been replaced by another page, and also just
>   before the applet is to be destroyed.

When you switch tab, I consider that the containing web page has been replaced hence it is logical that `stop()` is invoked.

> Can I disable that, I want stop never been called.

No you can't, you don't have control on that. However, you could rely on the `init()` and the `destroy()` methods instead of `start()` and `stop()`. `start()` and `stop()` are meant for resuming/pausing anything that consumes resources which are not necessary if not visible (for example an animation is pointless if not visible).

Comment: "No you can't, you don't have control on that." - that's ridiculous I think. "However, you could rely on the init() and the destroy()" what it would be in my case?

Comment: @NikolayKuznetsov _that's ridiculous I think_ I don't understand what you are targetting? `start()/stop()/init()/destroy()` are methods meant to be overriden to be notified of particular events that only the browser can send you. You need to use them appropriately. `init()/destroy()` are invoked once. `start()/stop()` can be invoked several times.

Comment: Ok, I would need to think how to refactor it.

Comment: So if I want the applet to be running non-stop (regardless of whether I minimize the browser window or switch to another tab), then I should provide an empty stop() method, because I want it to continuously run whether or not the page containing the applet is active/visible?

Comment: @WebUser the `stop()` method is invoked whenever your applet is not visible or when it is about to be destroyed. If for example, you have background resources running, you will provide a better user experience if you pause these resources and start them back when `start()` is invoked. If you have nothing to stop, then an empty `stop()` could be a valid implementation

Comment: @GuillaumePolet I need the applet to continue working even if its parent window is minimized or out of focus. So it sounds like I would need to implement an empty stop() method. Thanks for the clarification.