# Stop method not working, java applets

Tags: java, applet

I have a weird problem with my java applet. This is the java code :

```
import java.awt.*;
import javax.swing.*;
import netscape.javascript.JSObject;

public class JavaApplication11 extends JApplet {
    @Override
    public void init() { }

    @Override
    public void start() {
        repaint();
    }

    @Override
    public void stop() {
        JSObject window = JSObject.getWindow(this);
        window.eval("f1()");
    }

    @Override
    public void paint(Graphics g) {
        g.setColor(Color.white);
        g.fillRect(0, 0, this.getWidth(), this.getHeight());
        g.setColor(Color.yellow);
        g.fillRect(10, 10, 100, 70);
   }
}
```

And this is the HTML code :

```html
<HTML>
    <HEAD>
        <TITLE>Applet HTML Page</TITLE>
        <script>
            var number = 0;
            function f1() {
                console.log(number + " <-- ");
                number++;
            }
       </script>
   </HEAD>
    <BODY>
        <H3><HR WIDTH="100%">Applet HTML Page<HR WIDTH="100%"></H3>
            <P>
                <APPLET codebase="classes"
                    code="javaapplication11/JavaApplication11.class"
                    width=350 height=200>
                </APPLET>
            </P>
            <HR WIDTH="100%"><FONT SIZE=-1><I>Generated by NetBeans IDE</I></FONT>
    </BODY>
</HTML>
```

So I am having a simple applet that draws a yellow rectangle. I am trying to test the stop method. I tried to switch tabs, minimize the browser ( google chrome ) but the stop method never got called. Can anyone tell me why is this happening ?

Comment: From [the documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/applet/Applet.html#stop--): *It is called when the Web page that contains this applet has been replaced by another page, and also just before the applet is to be destroyed.* So clicking on a link within the page or closing the tab might help. Minimizing or putting in the background does not imply closing or replacing the page as it’s still open, just hidden.

Comment: Well I was reading this topic : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14137470/when-is-applet-stop-called
And people there say that its normal for stop be activated on tab switching and browser minimizing.

Comment: That’s a browser-specific behavior. If the specification doesn’t mandate it, don’t rely on it. And note that the entire question is about an “Applet Viewer”, not a real browser…